# App is not compatible with TVs on closed testing in the Google Play. This item is not compatible with your device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, android-tv

I'm developing an app for Android TV and TV-boxes.
My problem is that Android TV devices are available for installing my app from Google Play for **internal** testing, but NOT available for **closed** testing (but it still can be installed on the smartphones).

Screenshot: Google Play install dialog

[image: Screenshot: Google Play install dialog]

My app starting from StartScreenActivity (it's splash screen).
The QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES is required for my app and declared.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:banner="@mipmap/appbanner">
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.presentation.StartScreenActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.presentation.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:exported="false">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

On the internal testing it works like expected, but no one can to install an app to TV on the close testing. Setting the **android.software.leanback** as required not helped - it just making all others devices not available for install.
What am I doing wrong? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was non-obvious, but all you need is to add Android TV form factor to the Google Play Console:
**Release** -> **Advanced Settings** -> **Form Factors** -> **Add**

[How to add the form factor to the Play Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIRYx.jpg)

I waited over 24 hours before my application was approved.
Now all TV devices are available.